# Voting to close a question after gaining the close privilege should invalidate any pre-privilege flags

Tags: bug, review, flags, vote-to-close

This bug is very much an edge case, and here's how it goes:

1. Flag a post with <3k rep:

> [image]

2. Earn 3k total rep

3. Go to the Close Votes review queue; observe your flag:

> [image]

4. Open the review task:

> [image]

5. Attempt to <kbd>Close</kbd>:

> [image]

Except I *didn't* already vote to close the question; it's referring to my flag.

The result is I am unable to close the question.

Comment: Danny, you should add your findings, that you posted below, to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Like you said, it *is* an edge case (after all, we cross the 3k barrier every day, all over again, don't we?).

Also, given the fact that it would be removed from the close queue sooner or later (by 5 other users), I'd say that while correct, this bug is a [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) at best.

Comment: I've made another discovery. I figured I can invalidate my flag by editing the offending question, so I did that. This changed my flag to *helpful*. However, I still can't close the question. I get the same error. It's treating the flag as a close vote, regardless of whether or not it's been handled. So in theory, anything which has been flagged cannot be closed.

Comment: I just tested my theory, it's absolutely correct. I flagged [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186272/cant-mention-more-than-one-user-in-a-comment-on-my-question) as a duplicate a few hours ago. I cannot close it - same error. Same deal on all my other flags, regardless of when they were flagged, and whether it has been handled.