# Addressing A Comment To More Than One Person?

Tags: feature-request, comment-replies

Is it possible to address a comment to more than one person ?

Answer (score 2):

No - the @ ping only is coded to alert one person from a single comment.

In practice, I've used the [chat] link to draw more than one person into the main chat room (or made a custom room) to discuss a post whenever I felt I wanted to get several people's attention.

At that point, I could @ping each of them on one chat line and not pollute the comments thread with too much discussion.

---

That being said - I'll send this feature request to the main meta where all sites can weigh in since all share a common code base. The fastest route to this change would be to build consensus on meta.stackoverflow.com rather than a child meta.

- [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)
- [Can't mention more than one user in a comment on my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186272/cant-mention-more-than-one-user-in-a-comment-on-my-question)

Comment: I appreciate it would have to be a feature of all SE sites & not just AskDifferent. But if it is quite straightforward to implement, it could prove to be very useful

Comment: Whichever you think would be best ?

Comment: I guess migration is fine :)